# It's All About Earthquake!

Tags: earth, earthquake

All the following informations i've got are from a book.(i want to check that whether the informations are correct or not,that book isnt a science book though)
There is a limit to which earth can vibrate,earth can't vibrate more than that limit. That's why we feel almost same vibrant for 6 and 7 richter scale earthquake.Eventually we feel highest earth's vibrant during 6 richter scale earthquake,no matter how big magnitude in richter scale is we almost feel the same vibrant as 6 richter scale.
Are all these information correct?
From my experience i didnt feel the recent 6 richter scale earthquake but i did feel the 7.6 richter scale recently happened in Nepal,as i live in Bangladesh(south asia)

Comment: The moment magnitude scale (pretty similar to the Richter scale) is the total amount of energy release in an earthquake.  If a really big earthquake shakes for a long time the energy release can be spread out and feel weaker than a lesser earthquake that happened much faster.  For how an earthquake feels, you should look at the peak ground acceleration and surface waves.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the subjective perception of earthquake strengths, and not physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking how intense the earthquake feels, this is well described by the [peak ground acceleration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_ground_acceleration) (PGA). By this I mean that the sensations people report are [well correlated with the PGA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_ground_acceleration#Comparison_of_instrumental_and_felt_intensity).

The [Richter scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richter_magnitude_scale) measures the energy released by the earthquake, but this is not necessarily correlated with the PGA and therefore with what people feel. It depends where the energy is released, how fast it is released and probably lots of other things I haven't thought of.

To go back to your question, I'm not sure there is any limit to how fast the ground can vibrate i.e. how big the PGA can be. The article I've linked includes a table giving magnitude and PGA for [a number of notable earthquakes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_ground_acceleration#Notable_earthquakes). From a glance at the data there is no obvious plateau in the PGA values. The table nicely illustrates the lack of correlation between Richter magnitude and PGA.

Googling will find you [various measurements of the peak ground acceleration for the recent Nepal earthquake](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=nepal%20earthquake%202015%20peak%20ground%20acceleration). For example [this map shows the maxium PGA was up to 0.4g](http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/shakemap/global/shake/20002926/), which is classed as *severe*.

Comment: http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eqarchives/year/eqstats.php from this link i can see that 1 richter scale change about 32times more or less energy but richter scale shows that 1 richter scale change 10 times energy..... isnt it contradictory?

Comment: The Richter scale measures the amplitude of seismic waves, which is related to the energy released. A change in magnitude of one means the amplitude of the seismic waves changes by a factor of ten and the energy changes by a factor of about 32. There are [full details on this site](http://earthquake.usgs.gov/learn/topics/measure.php) if you're interested in following this up.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is correct due to how the Richter scale functions. The Richter scale is in log 10. This means that to go up 1, you multiply by 10. Therefore, 7 is 10 times more powerful than 6.

Comment: So that means we will definitely feel the impact of 7 richter scale 10x powerful than 6 richter scale?